# Reducing poly count on circular insets?

Tags: modeling

I want to merge the vertices together to make them all tris, but keeping the circle in the middle. Basically reducing the polycount from 32 to 16 on the inner loop.

[image]

I feel like there should be a simple way to do this, but Im not sure how. Right now I just manually select the vertices and merge at center. Like so,

[image]

The problem with that is, I end up having to do it twice sometimes if I've already extruded the plane before merging or if i started with a cylinder.

[image]

I understand you can mirror the object but in the instance of it being non symmetrical, (in this case mine is tapered), you would have to start with a plane and do the merging first.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. select the middle circle
2. select>checker deselect
3. set pivot point to individual origins
4. scale down to zero
5. mesh>cleanup>merge by distance